# KDE/Qt5 Minimize animation wrong target with own dock application

Tags: qt5, minimize, kde-plasma, dock

Recently I started to work on KSmoothDock to add more customization options, as to my liking. I added few options, but there is one bug persisting from original project: KDE seems to not recognize position of the launchers on the dock, and minimize animation (be it scale or djinn effect) target is a place where the user clicks - so the window minimizes to either minimize button, or if the user clicks on the dock, it minimizes to the dock (how it should be at all times). Not sure how I should tackle the issue. Could someone help me with this :)?

I reviewed some other docks, but I found no hints that would lead me to fixing this bug. Also KDE/Qt5 documentation wasn't helpful.